# Product page, attributes

Tags: attributes

I need to create a table in page product.

Now my code work well but, in some products, there is white space in table.

My code:

```
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col />
    <tbody>
    <?php $_totale=count($_additional); $_contatore=0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <?php if (!strpos(($_data['code']),"filtro")) { ?>
        <?php if ($_data['value']!="No" ): ?>
            <?php if ($_contatore%2==0): ?>
            <tr>
            <?php endif; ?>

                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <!--<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>-->
                    <td class="data">
                    <?php #echo ">>".$_data['code']."<<"; ?>
                    <?php echo $_data['value']; ?>
                </td>
            <?php if ($_contatore%2==1): ?>

            </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $_contatore++; ?>
                <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
```

If use the "modulo" operation.

[image]

can you help me?

Comment: possibly `if ($_contatore%2==0):` needs to be the same after you close your td. also why are you using <th> tag next to <td> tag?

Answer (score 0):

if i use

```
<td>
```

and replace

```
<th>
```

with

```
</tr>
```

(the code)

```
<?php if ($_data['value']!="No" ): ?>
            <?php if ($_contatore%2==0): ?>
            <tr>
            <?php endif; ?>

                    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></td>
                    <!--<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>-->
                    <td class="data">
                    <?php #echo ">>".$_data['code']."<<"; ?>
                    <?php echo $_data['value']; ?>
                </td>
    </tr>
            <?php if ($_contatore%2==1): ?>

            </tr>
```

[image]

if i remove :

```
</tr>
```

[image]

there is a hole.